# Load Additional Data While scrolling down a page using jQuery Ajax and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to apply the captioned feature in my project and decided to try it out to see how it works. But while testing it, it shows an Client script error with a message `Undefined` when I scroll to the bottom of the page. I do not know what I did wrong in my code and I don't know how to get it to work. I am hoping someone helps me out of this. Below is the code:

**Repeater**

```
<div id="dvCampaigns">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptUsers" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;
               border: dashed 2px #04AFEF; background-color: #B0E2F5">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <b><u><span class="campaignname">
                      <%# Eval("CampaignName") %></span></u></b>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <b>Description: </b><span class="description">
                          <%# Eval("Description") %></span><br />
                          <b>ID: </b><span class="campaign-id">
                          <%# Eval("CampaignID") %></span><br />
                          <b>Date Created: </b><span class="datecreated">
                         <%# Eval("CreatedOn")%></span><br />
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="loader" alt="" src="../Images/loading.gif" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            rptCampaigns.DataSource = GetUserData(1);
            rptCampaigns.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public static TList<POLLice.Entities.Campaigns> GetCampaignData(int pageIndex)
    {
        int totalData;
        var items = new CampaignsService().GetAll(pageIndex, 10, out totalData);
        return items;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCampaigns(int pageIndex)
    {
        var dataset = GetUserData(pageIndex).ToDataSet(true);
        return dataset.GetXml();
    }
```

**jQuery Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageIndex = 1;
        var pageCount;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                GetRecords();
            }
        });
        function GetRecords() {
            pageIndex++;
            if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
                $("#loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns",
                    data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
            var campaigns = xml.find("Campaigns");
            campaigns.each(function() {
                var campaign = $(this);
                var table = $("#dvCampaigns table").eq(0).clone(true);
                $(".campaignname", table).html(campaign.find("CampaignName").text());
                $(".description", table).html(campaign.find("Description").text());
                $(".campaign-id", table).html(campaign.find("CampaignID").text());
                $(".datecreated", table).html(campaign.find("CreatedOn").text());

                $("#dvCampaigns").append(table).append("<br />");
            });
            $("#loader").hide();
        }
    </script>
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: debug your JS in the browser... And give us more specific data .. What exactly undefined

Comment: Thanks for your response Kram. On the Java script Console, It threw this error: POST `http://******/POLLiceWebApp/UserProfile/UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns 404 (Not Found)`. But the method it cannot find is in the code-behind. (Sorry I had to replace part of the url with '******' for security reasons).

Comment: Please test the following code without  UserProfilePrefix. Should be like this url: "Default.aspx/GetCampaigns",

Comment: @Kram That's what the url should be. But now I have this error on the javascript console: `500. Internal Server Error`. I don't know how to look out for the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax you have this line:

```
url: "UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns",
```

Did you remove the full path including http for this post or is that the way it is in your code? That needs a relative or absolute path to the web method. Also when calling web methods with ajax you need to use:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] //or whatever your return format is
[WebMethod]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Stephen. The url in my ajax as you noticed is exactly the way it is in my code. I also added this: `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]` but it didn't change anything. I still get the error.

Comment: I corrected the code to `url: "Default.aspx/GetCampaigns"` and the error I now get on the Javascript console is `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Any Ideas?

Comment: You need the full path on this line:
url: "UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns", example:
url: "http://yourWebsite.com/UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns", or url: "/UserProfile/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns", note the begining slash to start at the root of the site.

Comment: Try wrapping your data in a stringify like this: data: JSON.stringify({ pageIndex:  pageIndex }), and take out the single quotes. My guess here is that you have a type mismatch in the method signature and that's why it won't find your web method. You can test this faster by setting a breakpoint on your web method and using something like Postman or Fiddler to try to hit it. Note that JSON is an older library, you may need to use $.parseJSON(yourDataObject)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Someone else used this code and it worked. Could it be that it doesn't work on ASP.NET 2.0?

Comment: It works on 2.0. Your code looks correct other than it cannot find the endpoint. When you tried to hit "/Default.aspx/GetCampaigns" you got a 500, which is a server code error. You may have actually hit the endpoint that time but the param type was off. If you put the code out where you can provide a url I can hit it with Postman and tell you what you need to send to it.

Comment: It works now. I don't believe how simple the solution is that it took me so long to figure out, In my code-behind inside the GetCampaigns method, this was the simple change I made:                    `var dataset = GetUserData(pageIndex).ToDataSet(true);` to            `var dataset = GetUserData(pageIndex).ToDataSet(false);`.  In casting to dataset, I set the "IncludeChildren" to true which was the cause of the confusion.  Thanks very much for giving me the hint that the issue was coming from server. Wish it was a proper answer so I could mark it as the right answer.